# collection view with empty content, even if protocols and delegates are defined

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

below is the Triggered viewController which holds CollectionView and its properties:

```
 import UIKit

struct CellModel {
    let imgImage: UIImage
    let carNumber: String
    let locationInfo: String
    let modifiedDate: String
    let modifiedBy: String

}

class MerchandizeEntranceViewController: UIViewController {


    let data: [CellModel] = [CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim"),CellModel(imgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "car"), carNumber: "11, 23, 34", locationInfo: "Seoul, South Korea", modifiedDate: "12-01-2020 at 6:30pm", modifiedBy: "Mr.Kim")]



    let idCell = "idCell"
    @IBOutlet weak var customCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        customCollectionView?.dataSource = self
        customCollectionView?.delegate = self
       customCollectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: idCell)





    }

}





class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var carNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationInfo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modifiedDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modifiedBy: UILabel!


    public func configModel(with model: CellModel ) {

        imgImage?.image = model.imgImage
        carNumber?.text = model.carNumber
        locationInfo?.text = model.locationInfo
        modifiedDate?.text = model.modifiedDate
        modifiedBy?.text = model.modifiedBy
    }

}

extension MerchandizeEntranceViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

}

extension MerchandizeEntranceViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: 384, height: 100)

    }
}

extension MerchandizeEntranceViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: idCell, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.configModel(with: data[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }


}
```

and the below is " didSelectItemAt indexpath: " methods called inside my mainViewController which tiriggers the DetailedViewcontrolers (the above ViewController contents) show their contects:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell_Menu = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as? MenuCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue0", sender: AnyClass.self)
        case 1:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: AnyClass.self)
        case 2:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue2", sender: AnyClass.self)
        case 3:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue3", sender: AnyClass.self)
        case 4:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue4", sender: AnyClass.self)
        case 5:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue5", sender: AnyClass.self)
        case 6:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue6", sender: AnyClass.self)


        default: NSLog("no view is defined for this cell")

        }
    } else {
        if let cell_Story = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "storyCell", for: indexPath) as? StoryCell {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                NSLog("No addidtional view defined for story cell yet.. .")
            default: break

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Can AnyOne please look it through and correct me if anything is wrong with this piece of flow of code.. certainly something is wrong with it.. .

Comment: did you check your IBOutlet?
does it have the reference of UICollectionView

Comment: sure, I did.. It has the reference.. . all connected..

Comment: first register 
1.
customCollectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: idCell)

2.
customCollectionView?.dataSource = self
customCollectionView?.delegate = self

3. 
customCollectionView?.reloadData() //although it does not necessory for your case

Comment: Unrelated but dequeueing a cell outside of `cellForRowAt` is pointless particularly the cell is unused anyway. And what is the weird parameter `AnyClass.self` for? And if you are using  prototype cells you **must not** register the cells.

Comment: @vadian, lol.. Yeah I know it is weird but otherwise other collection View's cell s too got pressed and triggers to the same viewController which makes it look even more weird.. lets say, i got 2 different collection views with different number of cells, and if i dont use " dequeue"  both cells in the both collection views keep showing the same content even when they have different contents each.. that's why i kept it there tmporarily to check first if the views are working.. . )

Comment: If *both cells in the both collection views keep showing the same content* your design is wrong. If you have two different collection views check the instance against the passed `collectionView` parameter.

Comment: @supranjowti, thanks for your answers, however, it didnt work, still empty contents and besides if you look at my code, i aready did it with the datasource and delegate inside the viewDidLoad() and if I remove " Register class" app crashes.. .

Comment: @O_S I do not say to remove Register's class. I said, first Register then set delegates.

Comment: @O_S log a print in the cellForItemAt. does it fire the delegates?

Comment: yeah, it fires the delegate.. log statement prints.. .)

Answer (score 1):

Let me do an example, let's say you are using prototype cells and registering on the code, you'll not use the same Class to construct them. The class to the registered cells will not have any IBOutlet (nothing from storyboards):

```
let regCell = "regCell"
...
customCollectionView.register(RegCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: regCell)
...
class RegCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var textField = UITextField()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ...
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And, in the same project you decide to use a prototype cell:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
class ProCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
}
```

To handle those two different types of implementing a cell, your `cellForItemAt` **could** be:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
        // Setting Registered cells
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: regCell, for: indexPath) as! RegCell
        cell.textField.placeholder = "Registered Cell"

        return cell
    } else {
        // Setting Prototypes cells
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: proCell, for: indexPath) as! ProCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .gray
        cell.label.text = "Prototype"

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Thats just an example of implementation, you can use those cells on the same collectionView or not. Hope I could help :)

Comment: they do same thing :)

Comment: If you use register you don't use prototype, it is one or another. If you choose to use register you need to get rid of the cell's outlets and set all it's items (UILabel, UIImages, etc) constraints on code.

Comment: @paulRick, so what you mean is a bit confusing to me, sorry to say that. can you please clarify it with an example..? i appreciate your comment tho.. .  thanks.. )

Comment: CollectionView is loading to the view but the cells are not being displayed.. /

Comment: no, It does not necessary to use items constraints by code. moreover, register cell by code is the best approach you should follow. you may need it in the complex UI

Comment: @supranjowti thanks alot.. and any idea why cells are not being displayed..? ;) collection view does, but its contents not showing up even if i see the scroll indicator scrolls through the view lol

Comment: @O_S check my answer. your custom cell have a nib file. right?

Comment: @O_S where did you create the design? is it inside the UICollectionview?

Comment: @supranjowti which design? all my design is in storyboard linked as outlets to controllers.. design is code based in controller after outlets linked..

Comment: @O_S paulRick edited the answer with a screenshot. it will work for your case. in the cell, items should have constraints to show.